# Leaflet layers Z-index

Tags: leaflet

I need to set z-index (control what is in foreground) between leaflet layers.

It is possible to e.g. control between 2 (or more) geoJson layers or between 2 (or more) ImageOverlay layers, with bringToFront, bringToBack functions.

L.geoJson layer is always over L.imageOverlay layer and I need to set imageOverlay to be over GeojJson.

**Is this possible in Leaflet?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but not using `bringToFront` and `bringToBack`. You need to use custom panes in the 1.0.0 version. See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178873/56906) on GIS.SE and [this tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes.html) on the Leaflet site. To summarize, you need to create a new pane for your image overlay, set its z-index, and then set the `pane` option when you create the layer. The following will add an image overlay above your GeoJSON layers:

```js
map.createPane('imagePane');
map.getPane('imagePane').style.zIndex = 401;
var imageLayer = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {
  pane: 'imagePane'
}).addTo(map);
```

Of course, you can also place GeoJSON layers in their own pane(s) and manipulate their z-indexing as well.

Comment: Thanks Nathan!
I did not know about this options- works great.